# Check celery config with command line

Tags: celery

I have celery running in a docker container and I want to check that the option `CELERY_TASK_RESULT_EXPIRES = '3600'` has been applied.

I tried using `celery inspect conf` and `celery inspect stats` but the commands never end. Other than that celery is running fine and doing its work.

Answer (score 8):

You can get that from celery inspect. Try this

```
celery -A app inspect report --timeout 10
```

Answer (score 2):

Found [flower](https://pypi.org/project/flower/). It is installed with

```
pip install flower
flower -A celery-app-name --port=5555
```

And then celery can be accessed via REST API. The following will give the workers config

```
curl -w "\n" http://localhost:5555/api/workers
```